# Image is pixelated while calling toDataURL() of three.js canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl

Using three.js I rendered a 3D model, there is no anti aliasing issue in the Rendered model, but when I call:

```
renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
```

it return an image url which is pixelated.

**[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/art388yv/)** that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you have tried.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/art388yv/) is one I prepared earlier.

Comment: Works fine on my Chrome; the image looks nice and smooth... Which browser are you using?

Comment: Safari om the Mac is fine, too.

Comment: solved my issue by `THREE.FXAAShader` and calling 'composer.render();' on onload of  `THREE.LoadingManager()`